# Database of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, computer-science

I have an idea about simple graphs that seems to check out for all cases which I have randomly generated on my computer. They were generated over a variety of vertex counts, where I included edges with some probability $p$, which I tested for various values.

I know that up to 10 vertices, there are not too many graphs (see [oeis](https://oeis.org/A000088)). Also, there are many specific graph which have served as counterexamples to other peoples ideas in the past.

Are there any good lists of graphs that are freely available online? I feel like checking many randomly generated graphs might be repeating lots of work.

Comment: One of the links on the OEIS page is to a paper which links to [House of Graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org), one such database.